# Meaning of "pour out" in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could anyone please rephrase the words "pour out" in the following sentence?

Everyone poured out to sit in the various sections for the Emperor and the officials and the Queens all around the lake."

I am trying to make a logical connection between "poured out" and "to sit in".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more context. It is impossible to rephrase those words without it.

Comment: They are about to watch a dance performance. It is a celebration honoring the full moon.

Comment: to pour out [of a building or place].

Comment: You could replace with: (1) ***turned out***; (2) ***erupted***; (3) ***burst***; (4) there is no step 4 — please consult a thesaurus :o) [in the context, only the first is remotely as fluent as *poured out*, so I’d leave it as it is]

Comment: Can the sentence be rephrased as follows:

There was a great crowd in the various sections for the Emperor and the officials and the Queens all around the lake."

Comment: Not quite; *poured out* describes the movement of the people, the formation of the crowd.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, "poured out" is a phrase meaning "a large group leaving a building."

A class of school children rushing to recess might be said to "pour out" onto the playground.  If an apartment building caught fire, the tenants might "pour out" into the parking lot to await the fire brigade.

The restated sentence might look something like:  "Everyone quickly exited the building to sit in the various sections for the Emperor and the officials and the Queens all around the lake."